# Asignar una variable luego de if

Tags: java, condiciones

Saludos quiero luego de que valide el if se asigne una de los dos condiciones pero me sale siempre en null, si me pueden ayudar a resolverlo

```
String Time = VALID_UNTIL != null ? VALID_UNTIL.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""): VALID_UNTIL.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "")
```

si resulta con un valor null el valor `VALID_UNTIL` se asigna la hora actual.

Comment: Te refieres a que Time resulta con un valor "null" ?

Comment: si, resulta con un valor null pero si no es null que se asigner con el valor en caso de que no lo sea

Comment: Con que valor deseas se asigne ? @IssacValdez

Comment: con la hora actual en caso que no sea nulo

Comment: Si `VALID_UNTIL != null` reemplazas parte de su contenido y sino también lo reemplazas. Esto te tiene que generar un `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que el valor de `VALID_UNTIL` no es `null`, pero seguramente es una cadena con el valor de "null", por lo tanto debes agregar esta validación:

```
(VALID_UNTIL != null && !VALID_UNTIL.equals("null"))
```

Por lo que tu operación tripartita quedarìa de esta forma:

```
  String Time = (VALID_UNTIL != null && !VALID_UNTIL.equals("null")) ? VALID_UNTIL.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "") : new Date().toString();
```

Comment: Me funciono muchas gracias Jorgesys

Comment: Un placer, ayudarte, recuerda que es recomendable depurar para ver el valor de las variables, de esta forma puedes encontrar el problema o entender porque esta funcionando de manera incorrecta tu programa, @IsaacValdez saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
String time = VALID_UNTIL != null ? VALID_UNTIL.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "") : new Date().toString();
```

Con eso asignarás el valor de la fecha actual a tu cadena **time**, a partir de ahí puedes formatearla para adquirir solo la hora, solo la fecha o un formato especial que requieras.

Saludos...

Comment: igual me devuelve un null